# "The Tengwar are an artificial script..."

Tags: grammar

Reading up on Tolkien's Tengwar, I stumbled upon this sentence introducing its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar#Fictional_history_and_terminology):

> The Tengwar are an artificial script created by J. R. R. Tolkien

For me, mixing plural Tengwar with singular script makes this an awkward sentence, and I'm not entirely sure how it's even a correct one. I would rather have written "The Tengwar are artificial scripts...".

Comment: Tengwar are _one_ script, not several scripts. You could change the verb to singular, since _tengwar_ is not recognisably plural in English anyway; but there is nothing whatsoever wrong with the sentence as it stands now, either.

Comment: The nouns on either side of the verb *"to be"* don't have to agree in plurality. Would you say *"artificial languages are not a waste of time"*, or *"artificial languages are not wastes of time"*? I think the first one is clearly the correct choice.

Comment: ***All*** scripts are artificial. Languages do not come with orthographies.

Comment: It sounds weird if you don't recognize Tengwar as plural (tengwa being singular), and so perhaps a word like "constitute" instead of "are" might sound better all-around to those who do and don't recognize its plurality, but sounds no weirder than "The turtles are a menace to society according to Mr. Thompson"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments,

The nouns on either side of *"to be"* don't have to agree.

Would you say

> artificial languages are not a waste of time

or

> artificial languages are not wastes of time

I think the first one is clearly the correct choice.

[Taken from the comment by Peter Shor, Aug 29](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193832/the-tengwar-are-an-artificial-script#comment406031_193832)